# W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart

Tags: 12.04, apt, mongodb

I want to install MongoDB on Ubuntu. I am following the official instructions from [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Now when I do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it's giving me:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/ dist/10gen amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/downloads-distro.mongodb.org_repo_ubuntu-upstart_dists_dist_10gen_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/ dist/10gen i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/downloads-distro.mongodb.org_repo_ubuntu-upstart_dists_dist_10gen_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I have also removed this entry manually but when I do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it again downloads the same files. I don't know what the issue is. I want to install the latest MongoDB.

Comment: Deletion votes under this question don't make sense. Question is duplicate - sure, but deletion isn't necessary here. The post isn't offensive nor it is spam. Plus may point potential future users to the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you still have at least one MongoDB-related entry in your apt sources list, otherwise you would not see the error message.

Try running:

```
grep -r "mongodb" /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

to see which files still reference the MongoDB apt repository.

Note that the instructions in the MongoDB documentation tell you to put the repo definition in its own file under `sources.list.d`, rather than in the default `sources.list` file. It's a cleaner solution; I mention it in case it helps you track down your problem.